# How can i use 2 strtok in c?

Tags: c++, string.h

im working in c and im kinda new in this.
I have this string:

```
7EB3A50110140F3955025607EB7A50110140F3957730188
```

The packet starts at the "7E" so i used strtok(string,"E") to separate the 2 packets in this

```
B3A50110140F3955025607
B7A50110140F39577301887
```

now i want to eliminate the A,B,F of each token so i come up with this idea:

```
while(token!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<"addrT:"<<&token<<" value: "<<token<<"\n";
        token=strtok(NULL,"E");
        char *token1=strtok(token,"ABCDEF");
        while(token1!=NULL){
            token=strtok(NULL,"ABCDEF");
        }
        cout<<"addrT1:"<<&token<<" value: "<<token<<"\n";

    }
```

It didnt work at all so i wanted to check the address of each token with this code:

```
     token=strtok(string,"E");
    while(token!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<"addrT:"<<&token<<" value: "<<token<<"\n";
            token=strtok(NULL,"E");
            char *token1=strtok(token,"ABCDEF");
            cout<<"addrT1:"<<&token<<" value: "<<token<<"\n";

        }
```

And i figure it out that the second token uses the same memory address of my first token so what should i do to get the new token with the values ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What will you do if your data has "E" in the middle?

Comment: The "7E" its like the starter of the packet , so the only idea right now that i have its just to use the "E". I accept any suggestions!

Comment: What you're doing won't work if there's an "E" in the middle of the packet, for example "E5", "1E", etc.  Presumably, each pair of characters represents a byte, so work with the characters in pairs.

Comment: Why don't you just iterate over the string in search of "E7", instead of just 'E'?

Comment: `strtok()` relies on a static variable to keep track of the current parse location within a string. This implementation requires to completely parse one string before beginning a second string. Use `strsep()` if your compiler support it but then your code will not be portable. You can write you own implementation based on your requirement to parse the given string and split it into tokens.

Comment: Isn’t this C++ and not C?

Answer (score 0):

If your library supports it (i.e., defines `__STDC_LIB_EXT1__`), you could use [`strtok_s`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok). Note that you would have to define `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to `1` prior to including `<string.h>`, as `strtok_s` is an optional extension to the standard.

If you are coding for a POSIX target, you could use [`strtok_r`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r).

Note that I haven't checked your example code for errors; comments indicate that you might have other issues there beyond the need for two independent `strtok` calls.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are actually getting a different token.  You store the pointer returned from the first strtok call in `token` and the pointer returned from the second call in `token1`, but both of your output statements put out `token` and neither puts out `token1`.  That's why the values are the same.

Comment: Indeed that was the error, now i have better ideas of how to work with this.

Thank you guys!